# M2: The URL key for the selected store already exists

Tags: magento2, import

Sometimes during import products we receive issue:
*The URL key for the selected store already exists.*

**We have found one website with solution:**

https://www.human-element.com/url-key-specified-store-already-exists-magento-2/

but I see this path:
not be compatible with versions of Magento 2.1.8 and above

our version magento is 2.2.5

Can anyone check it for us if this solution will work on our version?

@update

We try install this path but during setup:di:compile issue:

```
 [Exception]
  Warning: Declaration of HE\UrlkeyRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::
  generateForGlobalScope($productCategories) should be compatible with Magent
  o\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::generateForGlobalScop
  e($productCategories, $product = NULL, $rootCategoryId = NULL) in /home/user/domains/website.com/public_html/app/code/HE/UrlkeyRewrite/Model/ProductU
  rlRewriteGenerator.php on line 50
```

code `producturlrewritegenertor.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace HE\UrlkeyRewrite\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\CanonicalUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\CategoriesUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\CurrentUrlRewritesRegenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\AnchorUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Service\V1\StoreViewService;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;

class ProductUrlRewriteGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator
{

    /**
     * Generate list of urls for global scope
     *
     * Update adds in a clone of the collection and setting the storeId
     * Variation of this post:
     * https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169352/magento-2-url-key-for-specified-store-already-exists
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $productCategories
     * @return \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[]
     */
    protected function generateForGlobalScope($productCategories)
    {
        $urls = [];
        $productId = $this->product->getEntityId();
        foreach ($this->product->getStoreIds() as $id) {
            if (!$this->isGlobalScope($id)
                && !$this->storeViewService->doesEntityHaveOverriddenUrlKeyForStore($id, $productId, Product::ENTITY)
            ) {
                // Default: $urls = array_merge($urls, $this->generateForSpecificStoreView($id, $productCategories));
                // before loading the category collection by looping it, clone it and set the correct store id,
                // so we get the correct url_path & url_key for that specific store id
                $storeSpecificProductCategories = clone $productCategories;
                $storeSpecificProductCategories->setStoreId($id);

                $urls = array_merge($urls, $this->generateForSpecificStoreView($id, $storeSpecificProductCategories));
            }
        }
        return $urls;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have change function generateForGlobalScope in file ProductUrlRewriteGenerator.php as below . It is working for me with Magento 2.3.2

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace HE\UrlkeyRewrite\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\CanonicalUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\CategoriesUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\CurrentUrlRewritesRegenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\Product\AnchorUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Service\V1\StoreViewService;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;

class ProductUrlRewriteGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator
{

    /**
     * Generate list of urls for global scope
     *
     * Update adds in a clone of the collection and setting the storeId
     * Variation of this post:
     * https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169352/magento-2-url-key-for-specified-store-already-exists
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $productCategories
     * @return \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[]
     */
    protected function generateForGlobalScope($productCategories,$product = null, $rootCategoryId = null)
    {
        $urls = [];
        $productId = $product->getEntityId();
        foreach ($product->getStoreIds() as $id) {
            if (!$this->isGlobalScope($id)
                && !$this->storeViewService->doesEntityHaveOverriddenUrlKeyForStore($id, $productId, Product::ENTITY)
            ) {
                // Default: $urls = array_merge($urls, $this->generateForSpecificStoreView($id, $productCategories));
                // before loading the category collection by looping it, clone it and set the correct store id,
                // so we get the correct url_path & url_key for that specific store id
                $storeSpecificProductCategories = clone $productCategories;
                $storeSpecificProductCategories->setStoreId($id);

                $urls = array_merge($urls, $this->generateForSpecificStoreView($id, $storeSpecificProductCategories,$product,$rootCategoryId));
            }
        }
        return $urls;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue in more than 3-4 projects.

If you want to resolve this issue, you can upgrade your version with latest one or try below code logic:

Try this solution by overriding below function in your custom module :)

Path: vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage

```
protected function doReplace(array $urls){ 
    $this->deleteOldUrls($urls); 
    $data = [];
    $storeId_requestPaths = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
        $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
        $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql); 
        if ($exists) continue;
        $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
        $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }

    // Remove duplication data;
    $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                unset($data[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        $this->insertMultiple($data);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
        /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[] $urlConflicted */
        $urlConflicted = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $urlFound = $this->doFindOneByData(
                [
                    UrlRewriteData::REQUEST_PATH => $url->getRequestPath(),
                    UrlRewriteData::STORE_ID => $url->getStoreId(),
                ]
            );
            if (isset($urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID])) {
                $urlConflicted[$urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID]] = $url->toArray();
            }
        }
        if ($urlConflicted) {
            throw new \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Exception\UrlAlreadyExistsException(
                __('URL key for specified store already exists.'),
                $e,
                $e->getCode(),
                $urlConflicted
            );
        } else {
            throw $e->getPrevious() ?: $e;
        }
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Thanks,

Ketan T.

Comment: worked for me in 2.3.4