# Category wrong url of subcategories key after save

Tags: magento2.4, magento-enterprise-2

Well i lost hope on this one, I hope somebody had similar issue

I have a following category structure

```
-xxx
  -a
   -b
     -f
     -g
     -h
   -c
   -d
```

xxx is the root category

The paths in the store for the categories **f,g,h** look now like:

```
http://page/a/b/f
http://page/a/b/g
http://page/a/b/h
```

Now I want to change the **-b **category url key to a different one.
Lets say, we change **-b to -lol**

So now the paths for the f,g,h categories should be

```
http://page/a/lol/f
http://page/a/lol/g
http://page/a/lol/h
```

But for some reason, one of the categories didn't change the url and was left with the old value:

```
http://page/a/b/g
```

So now I change the **-lol** category to **-something**

The results I receive are as follow

```
http://page/a/something/f
http://page/a/lol/g
http://page/a/something/h
```

What can be possibly the issue here and where could I look for an answer?
Saving the categories goes from admin panel, I don't have any features regarding plugins on save, just a magento2 EE edition

I also noticed that the url is not updated in the url-rewrite table (right away, only after the later save),
Mb there is some problem with some staging crp?

Comment: Tried reindexing?

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner of course

Comment: Dumb suggestions but, did you tried to update the path directly in database ? After doing that is the new path working ? If it is then I guess this is a workaround. That being said I aggree that something isn't normal. The answer might be in the code process running when you change yours paths.

Comment: didn't try that yet, I will give it a try probably tomorrow :)

Comment: @GosuPrzmak I have faced this type of issue and mentioned my answer step wise in the below link. can you go through it? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169352/magento-2-url-key-for-specified-store-already-exists

Comment: @JitendraPatel seems magento 2 is broken on categories, this happens when you use custom urls on root categories, then stuff in the system starts to go crazy, reproduced it on 2.4.4

Answer (score 1):

you should use

olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites

Magento 2 module which regenerates the url-rewrite, using the following link you can get an idea of how to use it.

https://www.measureddesigns.com/magento-2-regenerating-url-rewrites-products-categories/

install extension using

> composer require olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites

executes the standard Magento cmds as

- > php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- > php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- > php bin/magento cache:flush

and then execute olekoval cmd as

> php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate –entity-type=category

Comment: not sure if its working I think I did try and it was not
, I did use elgentos url rewrite https://github.com/elgentos/magento2-regenerate-catalog-urls
for sure this doesn't solve the problem, it's a tmp fix that comes back

Answer (score 1):

Seems Magento 2 is broken on category saving when you uncheck on a root category 'use default' under the 'url_key' property, then after few saves, it starts to break and some magic is happening, after I reproduced in on a demo online store, I rewrite the category saving :]